# Make Intellij use dependencies of Uber Jar

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management, uberjar

We have two modules A and B in our project. B depends on A. Module A is built as an Uber Jar, while module B finally builds into a war file. Since module A builds into an uber jar, we excluded all it's dependencies when adding it as a dependency for module B

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>*</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The only issue with this approach is that IntelliJ is reporting a bunch of undeclared imports in module B, despite the fact that these are obtained from A through the uber jar.

Is there a way to make IntelliJ suppress these warnings or figure out that A is an Uber Jar and hence automatically use all it's dependencies for it's dependency analysis?

Comment: Uber jars are usually not meant to be dependencies. You build an uber jar to run it standalone, not to reference it somewhere else, because Maven handles the transitive dependency resolution. Can you explain why you build that uber jar?

Comment: How do you create uber jar? There could be an issue with maven-shade-plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93855 Could you create a report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project? Try as a workaround instead of declaring the excludes for the dependency specify it's scope as `provided`.

Comment: @JFMeier I agree, what we are doing is not optimal. The uber jar is used in a standalone way to run our pipelines. But, that module has a lot of utility classes that the other module uses. Ideally, we need to factor out this code into a separate module that both the other modules reference. Unfortunately, that is not in the plan for a while. Until then, is there a way to help out with my situation?

Comment: @Andrey I don't think the issue you referenced affects us. We do a couple of relocations, but the issue right now is that even the non relocated packages are not being identified by IntelliJ. Also, how do we specify a `provided` scope for the dependencies of B when adding B as dependency for A. If I'm not wrong, you can only specify B with `provided` scope. That's not what we are looking for. We want `B` to be included, just not any of it's dependencies.

Comment: @Hashken Does the build (with e.g. `clean package`) fail, or are these "just" IntelliJ errors?

Comment: @JFMeier Yup, the build passes. These are only IntelliJ errors.

Answer (score 0):

We have still not found a solution for this issue, but have come up with a workaround that solves our use case.

Instead of directly using module A (which builds to an uber jar), we created an empty module C, which will now build into an uber jar. Module A will now just build into a normal jar with all dependency jars present separately

```
A
|- B (war)
|- C (uber jar)
```

With this setup, we still get the uber jar we want from module C, all base dependencies are contained in a common module (A) and the war module (B) is able to import the module it depends upon (A) without any issue.